# how to insert array procedural in xampp 7 XAMPP Version 7.0.1

Tags: php, sql

```
foreach ($_SESSION["cart_products"] as $cart_itm)
{
    $product_code = $cart_itm["product_code"];
    $product_name = $cart_itm["product_name"];
    $product_qty = $cart_itm["product_qty"];
    $data=array(NULL,$product_code,$product_name,$product_qty);
    echo var_dump($data)."</br>";
}
```

`var_dump($data)`   echoes number of session product inside cart currently it has two product

```
array(4) { [0]=> NULL [1]=> string(5) "code5" [2]=> string(5) "popop" [3]=> string(1) "1" } 

array(4) { [0]=> NULL [1]=> string(5) "code3" [2]=> string(9) "red light" [3]=> string(1) "1" }
```

`xampp 7 XAMPP` Version 7.0.1
How to save exactly this `var_dump($data)` on another table?

Comment: You have you data saved in a $_SESSION, are you asking how to store that data into a database? Your question is not clear as to what you are asking.

Comment: echo var_dump($data) yes this data i want to save it on other table  implode but i dunno how to do it correctly ( XAMPP Version 7.0.1)

Comment: When you say "other table", you mean you want to save it into a database? the $_SESSION variable is NOT a database nor a good way to store data you want to be persistent. Look into setting up either MySQLi or PDO in PHP. Googling provided this as the first result for me: http://codular.com/php-mysqli

Comment: yes this table  INSERT INTO `trial`(`order_id`, `product_code`, `product_name`, `product_qty`) VALUES ([value-1],[value-2],[value-3],[value-4])

Comment: thank you   Damon Swayn i will visit it

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the very little details you are providing, and by mostly copying code from the tutorial I provided you I came up with this:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("db ip address", "db username", "db password", "database name");
$query = "INSERT INTO trial(order_id, product_code, product_name, product_qty) VALUES (NULL,?,?,?)";

if($mysqli->connect_errno > 0) {
    die('unable to connect to db');
}

foreach ($_SESSION["cart_products"] as $cart_itm) {
    $product_code = $cart_itm["product_code"];
    $product_name = $cart_itm["product_name"];
    $product_qty = $cart_itm["product_qty"];

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $product_code, $product_name, $product_qty);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    if(!$result) {
        die('insert query failed');
    }
}
```

Comment: finally it works yes i copy it from the tutorial for my school project :) very very helpful @Damon Swayn but the tutorial dont have save and the site was gone  thanks a lot you save me

Comment: If this solution worked, you should mark it as correct.

Comment: it work perfectly but i cant check it now, low reputation but i will  cuase this saves my life